# R - Error on one device only: Error in chol.default() : the leading minor of order is not positive definite, BVAR

Tags: r, error-handling, var, bayesian, mcmc

I am estimating an BVAR model in R and get the following error:

> Error in chol.default(V_post) : the leading minor of order 1 is not positive definite

Thats actually not the problem, since I work with data and model where this error could occur.

However, this only happens on my Lenovo Thinkpad X1. On my Dell XPS the algorithm starts drawing from posterior and everything seems to be fine.

So my question is: Given that I use exactly the same code and set.seed(), how can it happen that I get an error on one device only? Has anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: Are you using the exact same version of R? Are they using the same matrix libraries? You can usually check with `sessionInfo()`. Are you using the same package versions on both machines? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you, those are good questions - I will check the versions of R and packages and update my question afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I updated R on the machine which showed the error to the newest version and it solved the problem.